# getting contents (classes & modules) of required files in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, module

Is there any way, to track dynamically which classes or modules are included in required files.

a short example:

```
#my_module.rb
module MyCustomModule
  def foo
  end
end

#custom.rb
require 'my_module.rb'
#is here any way to track which modules are in the required 'my_module.rb' 
#without parsing the file or having some naming conventions?
```

The aim is, to require dynamically a bunch of files and including the contained modules in a class, regardless of how they are named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ObjectSpace` to determine newly defined Modules.

```
#custom.rb
existing_modules = ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).to_a
require 'my_module.rb'
new_modules = ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).to_a - existing_modules
 # => [MyCustomModule]

class X
  new_modules.each{|m| include m}
end
```

*Note*: You probably want to only include the top level ones, though, so check the names for `::`